# Style and change text content of children based on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to style a single div and change the text content based on whether the user clicks on the item or not.

At the moment the code is extremely repetitive and I am looking for a method that will help me rewrite it to both work more efficiently and look cleaner.

Thank you.

```
let lvl0,
lvl1,
lvl2;

lvl0 = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[0];
lvl1 = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[1];
lvl2 = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[2];

lvl0.addEventListener('click', changeStyle0);
lvl1.addEventListener('click', changeStyle1);
lvl2.addEventListener('click', changeStyle2);

function changeStyle0() {
  document.querySelector('.text-header').textContent = levelTitle[0];

  var showStyle = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[0];
  showStyle.style.opacity = '1';
  showStyle.style.backgroundColor = '#95a5a6';
  showStyle.style.border = '2px solid white';
  showStyle.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  console.log(showStyle);
}

function changeStyle1() {
  document.querySelector('.text-header').textContent = levelTitle[1];

  var showStyle = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[1];
  showStyle.style.opacity = '1';
  showStyle.style.backgroundColor = '#95a5a6';
  showStyle.style.border = '2px solid white';
  showStyle.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  console.log(showStyle);
}

function changeStyle2() {
  document.querySelector('.text-header').textContent = levelTitle[2];

  var showStyle = document.querySelector('.level-wrapper').children[2];
  showStyle.style.opacity = '1';
  showStyle.style.backgroundColor = '#95a5a6';
  showStyle.style.border = '2px solid white';
  showStyle.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  console.log(showStyle);
}

var levelTitle = ["Question about Drinks/Soda/Water.", "Question about Portion Control/Meals.", "Question about Salt/Sugar."];
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The method `document.querySelector` returns you only the first element in the document that fit the selector. To get an array of all the fits elements in the document, you have to use `document.querySelectorAll` method. For example:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.level-wrapper');
elemets[2].children[0].style = ...;
```

I think that this code is taking care of your issue:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.level-wrapper');

function showStyle(index, childIdx) {
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.opacity = '1';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.backgroundColor = '#95a5a6';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.border = '2px solid white';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  //console.log(levelStyle[index]);
}

function hideStyle(index, childIdx) {
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.opacity = '1';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.border = 'none';
  elements[index].children[childIdx].style.boxSizing = 'unset';
  //console.log(levelStyle[index]);
}

/*for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < elements[i].children.length; j++) {
    showStyle(i,j);
  }
}*/

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < elements[i].children.length; j++) {
    (function (index) {
      elements[i].children[j].onclick = function () {
      elements[i].children[j].is_show = !elements[i].children[j].is_show;
      if (elements[i].children[j].is_show) {
        showStyle(i,j);
      } else {
        hideStyle(i,j);
      }
      }
    })(j + i*elements[i].children.length);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="level-wrapper">
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>ccc</div>
  <div>ddd</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="level-wrapper">
  <div>eee</div>
  <div>fff</div>
  <div>ggg</div>
  <div>hhh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I greatly appreciate it. Although, the code styled all of the divs, versus just styling the one that is being clicked.

Comment: @JoshuaGarcia I edited the snippet code, try it now. When you click on element it's styles it, and in second click cancel the styling.

Comment: The code didn't exactly work the way I intended. I ended up figuring out the answer. Again thank you for helping me out along the way.

Answer (score 0):

This method ended up working for me.
Here is the Javascript:

```
function styleChange() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("level");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {

  let el = elements[0];
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName === "LI") {
       el.classList.remove("active");
     }
     el = el.nextSibling;
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  };
 }
}
styleChange();
```

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="level-wrapper">
    <li class="level">
      <a href="#" class="level-link"></a>
      </a>1</li>
    <li class="level">
      <a href="#" class="level-link"></a>
      </a>2</li>
    <li class="level">
      <a href="#" class="level-link"></a>
      </a>3</li>
</ul>
```

And finally the css:

```
.active {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```